# Will I be refused a visa if I previously overstayed in a different country?

Tags: visas, schengen

I went to South Africa and overstayed there for some months.

Might I be refused a visa for Sweden because I overstayed in South Africa?

Comment: My answer covers short-stay Schengen visas, is that what you applied for?

Comment: @Relaxed, your answer (+1) covers EVERYTHING. It means there is no type of visa where the decision-make is indifferent to a breach. If the OP gets caught out, it will be a possible show-stopper.

Comment: @GayotFow I would think spouse visas might be a bit different, at least in some countries.

Comment: @Relaxed, for spouses they do not worry about overstaying (different topology), but there are tons of other compliance and character aspects they will consider when the applicant has performance problems.  We should edit the question title so as to address a global audience.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether they notice it (you don't have to disclose anything like that on the form like you do for other countries) and probably on the rest of your application.

If they do notice it, it might lead to a refusal, not because there is any formal rule that bans people who overstayed elsewhere but because it goes to your credibility: You now say you will leave the Schengen area in three months time but the last time you implicitly did that (namely for your visit to South Africa), you actually stayed longer illegally.

So the consulate could legitimately rule that your “intent to leave the territory of the Members states before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained”, which is one of the standard reasons to refuse a visa.